# Is there any java library to check if given Date meets criteria given in String?

Tags: java, date

Im looking for a java library that can check if given Date meets criteria given in string, for eg.:

- YYYY.MM.DD -  specific day, eg. 2002.04.01.
- YYYY.MM.DD-YYYY.MM.DD - days in range, eg. 2002.02.01-2002.11.20.
- DD - day of month, eg. 04 (fourth day of every month).
- DD-DD - range of days in month, eg. 04-15 (from fourth to fifteenth day o every month)
- DAY - day of week, possible values: MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN.
- DAY-DAY - range of days in week, eg. MON-FRI (working days).
- HH24:MI-HH24:MI - time range with minute precision, eg. 02:15-17:30.

Interface should look like:

```
public boolean checkDate(Date testDate, String criteria);
```

Comment: And how do you intend to use this ? What will be your inputs ?

Comment: if (DateCheckLibrary.checkDate(myDate, "02:15-17:30"))
  System.out.println("cool");

Comment: I think you may have to use one format string also even if you find a library. Simple thing is to use the `SimpleDateFormat` as suggested by Peter Lawrey

Answer (score 1):

Java itself has rich Date and calendar API, you can check various examples on google.

here is one of them,
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html

Also check Calendar API
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

For Date API check
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Comment: I'm looking for a far more complex solution.

Comment: The above mentioned things can be done using JAVA Date API, can you please mention what other complex operations you need to do?

Comment: i would like to allow user to enter a time period in any of above formats and check if some Date object is in that period via call checkDate(Date testDate, String criteria) or something similar

Comment: Java 5.0 entered EOL almost 4 years ago, doesn't stop people using it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in SimpleDateFormat with Calender, or you could use JodaTime.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat with Calendar or Joda time doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: You would need to write some code of your own, but not much. ;)

Comment: sloth is the mother of progress :)